# controlling mousewheel events flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mousewheel

I'm working on a menu system in flash. If the mousewheel scrolls up each menu item shift up and visa versa for mouse wheel scrolling down.

The problem I have is there seems to be multiple "steps" going on.

In my mouse wheel handler I trace out the text "wheel" to test.
If I mouse the mouse wheel just once  "wheel" gets traced out twice. So for every one mouse wheel move my handler is being called twice and thus the scrolling of my menu always skips an item.

Any tips?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answer is no longer valid, but cannot delete because it's 'accepted'.

Comment: In my menu class that extends MovieClip I have just added 
addEventListener(mouseEvent.MouseWheel,myFuntion).

It's peculiar alright. I'm developing on a laptop with a mouse plugged in. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer for this question; for one thing, the code posted is in the wrong language and will not work in ActionScript 3.